# Getting notifications from the wrong app

Tags: bug, android-app, stack-overflow-app

I have installed both the Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow Android app on my mobile phone. I'm active only on Stack Overflow and since I installed the new app I was receiving notifications on the Stack Overflow app (no more notifications from the Stack Exchange app). This was expected as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/16/stack-overflow-official-app-launches-ios-android/?cb=1):

> If you decide to download both apps, your notifications will be split between the two. Your Stack Overflow notifications will appear in the Stack Overflow app, and all other Stack Exchange notifications will appear in the Stack Exchange app.

In the last days (*probably* after updating Stack Exchange app to `1.0.95`) I'm receiving notifications from the wrong app (the old Stack Exchange app).

I've logged in in both apps and notifications are enabled for both apps.

Stack Exchange version is `1.0.95` while Stack Overflow app version is `1.0.4`. I'm using Android 7.0 on Samsung Galaxy S7.

Comment: _Bin the new app_. I'm half serious, it's _almost_ pointless. I'm not one to take a step backwards and I've both installed but the new app is just so limited, even for SO.